# White Leaf Bromeliad

Tags: identification

I have a white leaf bromeliad.  I have never seen a mostly all white bromeliad plant.  It grew with a green with white stripes bromeliad plant.  Does anyone know if it's rare and does it have a name?

Comment: Hi Mary, we need a picture or two to identify the bromeliad,  there are many different types and appearances

Answer (score 1):

There are a *lot* of bromeliads out there, but you can take a look at the [Bromeliad Cultivar Register's website](https://registry.bsi.org/?) to see if you can find any that match yours.  I don't think we can offer you more help than that without a picture or more information.

I am not involved in bromeliad world, but I'm seeing cultivating pale variegated bromeliads is a [hobby for some folks](https://go.gale.com/ps/i.do?id=GALE%7CA610341898&sid=googleScholar&v=2.1&it=r&linkaccess=abs&issn=00908738&p=AONE&sw=w&userGroupName=tel_oweb&isGeoAuthType=true&aty=geo) (pretty cool hobby!).  Does yours look anything like these?

[image: Picture of Alcantarea "Bobby Gold" by Peter Tristam, a bromeliad with pale yellow leaves with green stripes at the edges]

[image: Alcantarea 'John Stoddart', from Elimbah Tropicals, Australia, picture of the plant with largely white leaves and green stripes down the edges]
*Alcantarea 'John Stoddart', from Elimbah Tropicals, Australia*